# python curl unable to PUT empty content type in header

Tags: python, python-3.x, curl, subprocess

trying to do a PUT using curl and python subprocess, however, I am unable to set the content type for my request.

```
import subprocess

item = '{"title": "Copy", "id": "1mglMSA_wU", "type": "document", "parentId": "1WtlhD7a", "modifiedTime": "2019-01-16T21:33:36.631Z", "createdTime": "2019-01-16T21:29:26.327Z", "shared": "True"}'
cmd = f'curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X  PUT localhost:9200/ax/_doc/1?pretty  -d\'{item}\''

res = subprocess.Popen(f'ssh {user}@{host} {cmd}', shell=True,
                       stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()
print(res)
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
{
  "error" : "Content-Type header [] is not supported",
  "status" : 406
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The remote `ssh` command invokes another shell, so you need to escape strings twice, or - much better - get rid of one shell if you can.

Also, you are reinventing `subprocess.run()`, with several bugs.

```py
import subprocess

item = '{"title": "Copy", "id": "1mglMSA_wU", "type": "document", "parentId": "1WtlhD7a", "modifiedTime": "2019-01-16T21:33:36.631Z", "createdTime": "2019-01-16T21:29:26.327Z", "shared": "True"}'

res = subprocess.run(
    ['ssh', f'{user}@{host}',
     'curl', '-H', 'Content-Type: application/json',
             '-X', 'PUT', 'localhost:9200/ax/_doc/1?pretty', '-d', item],
    capture_output=True, text=True, check=True)  # no shell=True
print(res.stdout)
```

I can see no particular reason to put the command in a separate variable, though if you like, you can of course put it in a list and then interpolate the things you need into the list before you pass it to `subprocess.run()`.

Perhaps see also [Actual meaning of 'shell=True' in subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess)

The immediate problem is that you were passing simply `-H` `Content-Type:` because one layer of quotes was getting peeled off.

Comment: `subprocess.run()` was introduced in Python 3.5. `capture_output` and the alias `text` for what was previously only called `universal_newlines` was introduced in 3.7. Perhaps see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256107/running-bash-commands-in-python/51950538#51950538 if you need compatibility with earlier versions.